# Detect previous row of selected one with CSS and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            ...
        <tr>
        ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            ...
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            ...
        </tr>
        <tr> I click here but I want that class refers to the previous row
            <td></td>
            ...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I add, with jQuery, a class to the clicked row. I want that class refers to the previous row of the clicked one.

I suppose that I should use nth-child..?

Comment: `.prev()` might be useful here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery .prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) function to achieve this.

You'd use it like:

**HTML**

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Head</th>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> I click here but I want that class refers to the previous row</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr').click(function(){
        $(this).prev().css({"background-color":"pink"});
    });
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xuxoL5t5/)

Hope this helps!